# Why is LVS dropping packets?

Tags: xen, centos5, lvs

I am currently trying to get down to the core of a problem where my
LVS-director seems to drop a packet coming from a client from time to
time. We have this problem on our production systems and can reproduce
the problem on staging.

I posted this problem on the lvs-users-mailing-list and got no response so far.

## Our setup:

We are using ipvsadm with Linux CentOS5 x86_64 in a PV XEN-DomU.

### Current Version details:

- Kernel: 2.6.18-348.1.1.el5xen
- ipvsadm: 1.24-13.el5

## LVS-Setup:

We use IPVS in DR-mode, for managing the running connections we use
lvs-kiss.

`ipvsadm` is running in a heartbeat-v1-cluster (two virtual nodes), master
and backup are running constantly on both nodes.

For the LVS-services we use logical IPs being setup by heartbeat
(active/passive-clustermode)

The real-servers are physical Linux-machines.

## Network-Setup:

The VM acting as director is running as XEN-PV-DomU on a Dom0 using bridged networks.

### Networks "in play":

- abn-network (staging-network, used to connect the client to the director),
  used by the real-servers to send the answer to the clients (direct routing approach),
  used for ipvsadm slave/master multicast-traffic
- lvs-network: This is a dedicated VLAN which connects director and real-servers
- DR-arp-problem: solved my suppressing arp-answers on the real-servers for the service-ip
- The service-IP is configured as logical IP on the lvs-interface on the real-servers.
- In this setup ip_forwarding is not needed anywhere (neither on
  director, nor on real-server).

### VM details:

1 GB RAM, 2 vCPUs, system-load almost 0, memory 73M free, 224M buffers, 536M cache, no swap.

`top` shows almost always 100% idle, 0% us/sy/ni/wa/hi/si/st.

## Configuration details:

`ipvsadm -Ln` for the service in question shows:

```
TCP  x.y.183.217:12405 wrr persistent 7200
 -> 192.168.83.234:12405   Route   1000   0          0
 -> 192.168.83.235:12405   Route   1000   0          0
```

x.y first two octets are from our internal class-B-range.
We use 192.168.83.x as lvs-network for staging.

**Persistent ipvsadm-configuration:**
  */etc/sysconfig/ipvsadm*: --set 20 20 20

**Cluster-configuration:**
  */etc/ha.d/haresources*: $primary_directorname lvs-kiss x.y.183.217

**lvs-kiss-configuration-snippet for the service above:**

```
<VirtualServer idm-abn:12405>
  ServiceType       tcp
  Scheduler         wrr
  DynamicScheduler    0
  Persistance         7200
  QueueSize           2
  Fuzz              0.1
  <RealServer rs1-lvs:12405>
    PacketForwardingMethod  gatewaying
    Test ping -c 1 -nq -W 1 rs1-lvs >/dev/null
    RunOnFailure   "/sbin/ipvsadm -d -t idm-abn:12405 -r rs1-lvs"
    RunOnRecovery   "/sbin/ipvsadm -a -t idm-abn:12405 -r rs1-lvs"
  </RealServer>
  <RealServer rs2-lvs:12405>
    PacketForwardingMethod  gatewaying
    Test ping -c 1 -nq -W 1 rs2-lvs >/dev/null
    RunOnFailure   "/sbin/ipvsadm -d -t idm-abn:12405 -r rs2-lvs"
    RunOnRecovery   "/sbin/ipvsadm -a -t idm-abn:12405 -r rs2-lvs"
  </RealServer>
</VirtualServer>
```

idm-abn, rs1 and rs2 resolve via */etc/hosts*.

### About the service:

This is a soa-web-service.

## How we reproduce the error:

From a client we run constant calls to the web-service at an interval of one call in three seconds.
From time to time there will be a connection reset from the director to the client.

Interesting: This happens on n x 100th + 1 tries - interesting is the one.

### What we did to trace down the problem:

- Checked */proc/sys/net/ipv4/vs*: all values are set to default, so drop_packet is NOT in place (=0)
- tcpdump on client, fronted/abn of the director, backend/lvs of the directory, lvs and abn of the real-servers

In this tcpdump we could see a request from the client, answered by a
connection-reset by the director.
The packet was NOT forwarded via LVS.

I welcome any ideas on how to track this problem further down.
If any information is unclear/missing to drill down the problem - please
ask.

Answer (score 5):

Do you have any **stateful iptables** rules on the LVS-DR director? As I can see you are using port 12405, so if you have a rule like this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 12405 -j ACCEPT
```

In LVS-DR real servers are replying to requests from clients (and not the director), the director won't add those connections in the connection tracking table and the `FIN` packets won't be detected on the director's iptables with the rules `ESTABLISHED,RELATED`. Since you only allow `NEW` (`SYN`) packets on port 12405, `FIN` will be blocked. You have to use a **stateless firewall** on an LVS-DR director for load balanced services:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 12405 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: How would this explain the behaviour? Apart from that no, there are no rules like that on the director. And even if they were, the established,related would do just nothing (as - like you correctly noted on DR the real-server replies to the client directly).

Comment: I forgot to mention that the default rule for incomming is DROP and since `ESTABLISHED,RELATED` wouldn't do anything the director would drop the FIN packet.

If you don't have these rules, the only thing I could suggest is that you try to disable firewall on both the director and the real servers and see if that helps, but you probably tried that already.

Comment: Sadly yes. If we had Firewall problems the drop-rate would be much higher.